# C# calling constructor with abstract base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance

Scenario: More features need to add in existing code. In order to reuse my current code, I tried to create a base class and put all the common code in, and create multiple derived classes. However, the current class is depended on another class (grandparent class).

Here is the current code:

```
Class A {
    public A(int n) {
        ...
    }
}

Class B : A {
    public B(int n) : base(n) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I am trying to turn `Class B` into a `abstract base class`, so that I can have more derived classes from it.

Here is the idea:

```
Class A {
    public A(int n) {
        ...
    }
}

Abstract Class Base : A {
    protected B(int n) : base(n) {
        ...
    }
}

Class X : Base {
    public X(int n) : base(n) {
        ...
    }
}

Class Y : Base {
    public Y(int n) : base(n) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Theoretically, we shouldn't add a constructor to the abstract class. How can I deal with this gracefully? Any advice? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Who told you that we shouldn't add a constructor to the abstract class? We should and do it now and then.

Comment: it's absolute legit to have a constructor in abstract class.

Comment: The only rule of thumb that is worth while here, is if you are finding your self creating base classes, you should likely look at *composition* first (interfaces). Always prefer *composition* over *inheritance*

Comment: @MichaelRandall I thought about this. However, inheritance in this case may be more readable.

Comment: Theoretically stuff is hard to give advise on when we don't you the actual usage. but i agree with michael advice. its hard to try help as the usage and the knowing of what the problem is, is abstracted from us. Why isnt A an abstract class, and why cant you have many different abstracted classes if that what u want? what props or design consideration are you designing for?

Comment: @Seabizkit Thanks for your comment. The two derived classes that extend that base class are very similar.